# Does random.shuffle() uses uniform distribution?

Tags: random, python-3.5

I am using the following shuffling algorithm in my code to shuffle a list. But I would like to know what sort of distribution is assumed in `random.shuffle()`.

```
import random

random.shuffle(x)
```

where `x` is a list.

I read somewhere that random function in general uses uniform distribution but I could not find any clear information on random function page for [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

Does anyone know?

Comment: It uses the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Whether or not this is explicitly said in the documentation, it is both the obvious choice and clearly implemented in [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/random.py)

Comment: [How Python random shuffle works?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/215737/175972) on Software Engineering.SE.

Comment: Would this be called a duplicate then?

Comment: @JaideepShekhar It wouldn't be a duplicate of a question from another site, but is likely to be a duplicate of something here.

Comment: Thank you everyone. It is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Coleman wrote:

> It uses the [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle. Whether or not this is explicitly said in the documentation, it is both the obvious choice and clearly implemented in [the source](https://github.com/Python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/random.py)